# debug plugin using plugin registration tool CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have install profiler in one of my plugin step, which will executed on create of record.

Once i complete this, it generate a errorlog. I have copied that text and created a errorlog.txt. It looks like below :

**|7V3rkqM4ln4VR/6Y2I0uGzDGl2xXTuR1OmeqKnMys3on+k+HANnJFAY34KrK3tiIfYJ9i32H+d9vsk+yEjcD5iJ8AYxPdUd3gQVIOtI53znfkTT98/eF3vmKLVszjfdnQo8/62BDMVXNmL8/...**

When i upload that file, it gives me below error.

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Unable to parse the OrganizationServiceFault.
>   Parameter name: serializedReport
>      at PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerUtility.ExtractReport(String serializedReport)
>      at PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerUtility.DeserializeProfilerReport(String assemblyFilePath, String logFilePath, Boolean isCrmDataStream)
>      at PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerExecutionUtility.RetrieveReport(String logFilePath, Boolean isCrmDataStream)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.CommonControls.Helper.ParseReportOrShowError(Window window, FileBrowserView profilePathControl, Boolean requireReportParse, ProfilerPluginReport& report)
>   Inner Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: File does not contain a valid serialized OrganizationServiceFault.
>      at PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerUtility.ConvertFaultToStream(String serializedFault)
>      at PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerUtility.ExtractReport(String serializedReport)

I have already checked this link [Debug CRM 2013 Using Plugin Profiler error :](http://missdynamicscrm.blogspot.in/2014/05/debug-crm-2013-using-plugin-profiler.html) , but its not working.

Comment: Make sure you're selecting the correct files (profile, dll)

Comment: @Alex of course, i have checked that.

Comment: If you copy the text of your error into the question this will be much more easily found in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This will happen, if you download the wrong log file and feed into PRT for debugging.

- Correct log file:

Basically after installing profiler & the plugin step is profiled, once repro step is done in CRM, when trying to download the log file the prompt should read "Business Process error" and it should be encrypted & machine readable like below:

> **Download the details and load with Plug-in Profiler.
>   |7R1dc+I48q9QPGzdPRgbDMFhCVuzk8wttTsDFTJXW/tyJcttoosteWU5CfvrV7IN4cMBw0wM0ZIHgmS11OputVr.......**

- Wrong log file: (your case)

But not human readable like below:

> **System.Security.SecurityException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #D42EB3A1Detail:.......**

Comment: I am getting the correct log file, still the issue is same.

Comment: Are you saying that, still the log file you download from popup window with "Download the details and load with Plug-in Profiler. |7R1dc+....." text is not working ?

Comment: Yes. that's why i have to ask this question here.

Comment: am not sure without seeing your downloaded log file. you can try this solution if you want: https://dyaman.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/error-will-debugging-plugin-using-plugin-profiler-in-ms-crm/

Comment: This make sense to me: http://crm2011workingnotes.blogspot.com/2013/08/unable-to-parse-organizationservicefaul_11.html