# An error occurred while parsing the plugin profile from file

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I was connected CRM with **Plugin registration tool** of CRM SDK 2016 whenever i am uploading the downloaded error log file to debugger it's showing **"An error occured while parsing the plugin's profile from file"** could any suggest me where i am going wrong. The image is showing below:

[ErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IarbY.png)

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Unable to parse the OrganizationServiceFault.
>   Parameter name: serializedReport
>      at PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerUtility.ExtractReport(String serializedReport)
>      at PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerUtility.DeserializeProfilerReport(String assemblyFilePath, String logFilePath, Boolean isCrmDataStream)
>      at PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerExecutionUtility.RetrieveReport(String logFilePath, Boolean isCrmDataStream)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.CommonControls.Helper.ParseReportOrShowError(Window window, FileBrowserView profilePathControl, Boolean requireReportParse, ProfilerPluginReport& report)
>   Inner Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Message does not contain a serialized value.
>      at PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerUtility.ExtractReportFromFault(OrganizationServiceFault fault)
>      at PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerUtility.ExtractReport(String serializedReport)

Except this, when log file is downloaded it contains the below error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): SamplePlugins.PostCreateContact: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <ActivityId>8998bfd9-9637-430e-8c47-998c63d1f0ee</ActivityId>
   <ErrorCode>-2147220956</ErrorCode>
   <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
   <Message>Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): SamplePlugins.PostCreateContact: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.</Message>
   <Timestamp>2017-11-03T11:49:06.9775603Z</Timestamp>
   <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
   <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
   <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
   <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
   <TraceText>[SamplePlugins: SamplePlugins.PostCreateContact]
[e326c926-0dbe-e711-a94d-000d3af2242b: SamplePlugins.PostCreateContact: Create of contact (Profiled)]</TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Below is my **.CS** file:

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using System;

namespace SamplePlugins
{
    public class PostCreateContact : IPlugin
    {
        ITracingService tracingService;

        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
            tracingService.Trace("Tracing Execute");
            // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
               serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            // The InputParameters collection contains all the data
            //passed in the message request.
            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                // Obtain the target entity from the input parameters.

                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
                try
                {
                    // Create a task activity to follow up with the account customer in 7 days
                    Entity followup = new Entity("task");
                    followup["subject"] = "Send e-mail to the new customer.";
                    followup["description"] = "Follow up with the customer. Check if there are any new issues that need resolution.";
                    followup["scheduledstart"] = DateTime.Now;
                    followup["scheduledend"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
                    followup["category"] = context.PrimaryEntityName;
                    // Refer to the contact in the task activity.
                    if (context.OutputParameters.Contains("id"))
                    {
                        Guid regardingobjectid = new Guid(context.OutputParameters["id"].ToString());
                        string regardingobjectidType = "contact";
                        followup["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference(regardingobjectidType, regardingobjectid);
                    }
                    // Obtain the organization service reference.
                    IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
                    IOrganizationService service =
                       serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
                    // Create the followup activity
                    service.Create(followup);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*I have tried by replacing the **PluginProfiler.Solution.zip** but the issue still exists.*

Thanks.

Comment: Click 'Yes' in the error message box and get the actual exception & share here.

Comment: First do what @ArunVinoth suggests, but secondly, are you attempting to debug a plugin or register plugin?

Comment: Yes, i'm attempting a debug mode and i have updated the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [debug plugin using plugin registration tool CRM 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44131744/debug-plugin-using-plugin-registration-tool-crm-2013)

Comment: Yes i try to replace that PluginProfile solution but still same issues..

Comment: Make sure correct sdk version, plugin profiled, downloading right error log (human unreadable)..

Comment: As mentioned in the question, that is the only error message I am receiving while adding the error file. Except that, the error which is created in log file, I have updated the same in the question. Please have a look at that if it can help.

Comment: Crm log file content (which you are downloading from CRM & you are feeding into PRT)

Comment: Yes, It is the same content which I have updated in question.

Comment: Exception says FileIOPermission, are you writing any log file from CRM online sandboxed plugin, you can’t do that.

Comment: Click Reload organizations in your PRT, sort the plugins by Entity, verify if any other plugin steps (post create) registered in contact.

Comment: For FileIOPermission, I had a code but I have already removed that part. After removing it I deleted BIN folder and rebuild the solution. In PRT I have tried Reload Organizations but it is still not working for me.

Comment: may be silly, did you update the assembly in PRT after rebuild..?

Comment: Yes, After rebuild  i have updated the assembly in PRT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you below steps:

1. Unregister the Plugin assembly & Profiler
2. Download latest 365 SDK
3. Register the assembly freshly using new PRT from latest SDK
4. Install Profiler & try again
5. Most important - The error log you shared cannot be used to debug using Profiler. It will be different